# irrep over $\mathbb R$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be an abelian group such that $|G|=8.$

How many irreducible representations $G$ over $\mathbb R$ are there?

I know that dimension of those representations is $\leq2.$ AndThe number of irreducible representations $G$ over $\mathbb C$ is equal $8.$ I am not sure how to continue.

There are three abelian groups of order 8. Such as $C2 \times C4$, $ C2 \times C2 \times C2$
and $C8$

In case of $G=C8$
 Matrix $\begin{bmatrix}\cos {\frac{2\pi k}{n}} & -sin {\frac{2\pi k}{n}}\\\sin {\frac{2\pi k}{n}} & \cos {\frac{2\pi k}{n}}\end{bmatrix}$
 gives 3 2 dimensional irreps. Trivial and representation A (as $A(g^{2k+1})=-1$ and $A(g^{2k})=1)$ give 2 1 dimensional irreps.

In case of $G= C2 \times C2 \times C2.$ Consider $C2.$ Trivial and representation A (as $A(g^{2k+1})=-1$ and $A(g^{2k})=1)$ give 2 1 dimensional irreps of the group $C2$. Trivial and representation A (as $A(c)=-1$ ) give 2 1 dimensional irreps.  Matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$
 gives 1 2 dimensional irrep.  Then $ C2 \times C2 \times C2$ has $2\times 2 \times 2$ 1 dimensional  real irreps.

In case of $G=C2 \times C4.$ Consider $C4.$ 
 Matrix $\begin{bmatrix}\cos {\frac{2\pi k}{n}} & -sin {\frac{2\pi k}{n}}\\\sin {\frac{2\pi k}{n}} & \cos {\frac{2\pi k}{n}}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1\\1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$
 gives 1 2 dimensional irrep. Trivial and representation A (as $A(g^{2k+1})=-1$ and $A(g^{2k})=1)$ give 2 1 dimensional irreps.

Hence $G=C2 \times C4$ has 4 1-dimentional and 1 2-dimensional irreps.
I am wrong?

I edited after your comments.
I am grateful for all corrections, comments and response. I want to know if my thoughts are correct.

Comment: There are *three golden rules* for this site. ***Here are two of them:***
Explain what you tried and where you're stuck (showing your work is a good idea).
Don't ask for complete solutions to the problem—we're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: Try an example. Can you construct a specific real irrep of, say, the cyclic group of order $8$?

Comment: (except for the trivial one)

Comment: The number of irreducible representations over ${\mathbb R}$ will depend on which of the three abelian groups of order $8$ you are considering.

Comment: @user3533 I tried for the cyclic group of order $8$. I think that there are $2$ 1-dimensional irreps and 5 $2$-dimension irreps. Am I wrong?

Comment: The sum of dimensions is too large. Maybe some of your irreps are in fact isomorphic?

Comment: @user3533 Can I use the formula $\sum_{i=1}^{n} {n_i^2}=|G|$? Then there are 4 1-dimensional irreps and 1 2-dimension irreps

Comment: This formula works for complex reps, but usually not for real reps. Here it doesn't work.

Comment: I suggest you actually try to construct the irreps, and not use these counting considerations. You said correctly that the irreps are $1$ or $2$ dimensional. Try to construct a $2$ dimensional one. The vector space will be $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $x$ be a generator of the cyclic group of order $8$. A representation is determined by the linear operator (=matrix) mapped to by $x$. You are not free to choose any opearator you like. For example, you must send $x$ to a matrix $A$ such that $A^8=I$ (why?). Do you know such matrices?

Comment: @ user3533 Yes, I do. Matrix $\begin{bmatrix}\cos {\frac{2\pi k}{n}} & -sin {\frac{2\pi k}{n}}\\\sin {\frac{2\pi k}{n}} & \cos {\frac{2\pi k}{n}}\end{bmatrix}$ gives 3  2 dimensional irreps. trivial and representation A (as $A(g^{2k+1})=-1$ and $A(g^{2k})=1$) give 2  1 dimensional irreps

Comment: @ user3533 But what about other abelian group (non-cyclic)?

Comment: Ok. Great. Indeed, there are five nonequivalent irreps of $C_8$: Two one dimensional irreps, and three two dimensional irreps (given by rotation by $1/8,2/8,3/8$ times $2\pi$).

Comment: As for other abelian groups of order $8$? What are all of these groups? Find all of them. One is $C_2\times C_2\times C_2$. For this particular one, start by finding its complex irreps.

Comment: @ user3533 Are three abelian groups of order 8 (  Derek Holt tell about them)  $$C_2\times C_4,$$ $$C_2\times C_2\times C_2$$   and $C_8$? I understand how to continue. Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome. You may consider writing an answer to your own question here on the website, if you have the time.

Comment: user3533 I edited my question after your comments.
I am grateful for all corrections, comments and response. I want to know if my thoughts are correct.

Comment: I am glad to see you wrote your answer. Let's start with $C_2\times C_2\times C_2$. I suggest you start by finiding the complex irreps of this group first. You will see that there are $8$ of them, all one-dimensional, and in fact, they are real representations.

Comment: user3533  Oops I fixed it

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you're saying there. Anyway, there are only $8$ real irreps of $C_2\times C_2\times C_2$, and they are all $1$-dimensional.

Comment: And by the way, if you write '@' before my name, I will get a notification that you're saying something to me and will see it more quickly.

Comment: @user3533 $G=C2 \times C4$ has 4 1-dimentional and 1 2-dimensional irreps.
I am wrong? I am not sure what about 2-dimensional irreps. $C4$ has  it, but $C2$ has not.